# Pyspark: Convert Column from String Numbers to Timestamp Type

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking to convert Numbers in string format to timestamp.

Sample:

```
+--------+-------------------+
|date_str|expected date      |
+--------+-------------------+
|1.63E+15|1991-11-25 13:39:00|
|1.63E+15|1991-11-25 13:40:00|
|1.63E+15|1991-11-25 13:41:00|
+--------+-------------------+
```

I have tried using `to_timestamp()` but returning Null values. also converted to `unix_timestamp` but no luck.

```
sdf1.select(F.to_timestamp(sdf1.date_str, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').alias('date')).show()
sdf1.select(to_timestamp('date_str', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')).show()
```

Comment: what is exactly your number ? are you sure it is a string ? cause "1.63E+15" is different from "163000000000" in string ...

Comment: it is string...i have checked the schema

Comment: well, if it is a string, how can the timestamp be different at each line ? same input = same output. there is something wrong with your example

Comment: date column is what i expect after conversion

Comment: but do you understand that the same input produce the same output ? there is no magic when converting ... we cannont recover the lost digits.

Comment: what do you suggest, to first convert "1.63E+15" to integer and then to timestamp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238062/discussion-between-steven-and-martian-rover).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the transformation that you ask is not possible. The same input cannot produce different outputs. It should be :

```
+--------+-------------------+
|date_str|expected date      |
+--------+-------------------+
|1.63E+15|1991-11-25 13:39:00|  # Same "expected date" at each line
|1.63E+15|1991-11-25 13:39:00|
|1.63E+15|1991-11-25 13:39:00|
+--------+-------------------+
```

Then, the function you need is probably [`from_unixtime`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime) - converting a timestamp in numeric format to timestamp in string/timestamp format :

```py
time_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1428476400,)], ['unix_time'])

time_df.select(from_unixtime('unix_time').alias('ts')).collect()
# [Row(ts='2015-04-08 00:00:00')]
```

The only probleme is that, in your example, your numbers are 16-digits long (`E+15`) which is too much precision for a unix timestamp. You should probably divide it by 1000000.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

df.withColumn(
    "date_num", F.col("date_str").cast(T.DecimalType(16, 0)) / 1000000
).withColumn(
    "date", F.from_unixtime("date_num")
).show()
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|date_str|           date_num|               date|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|1.63E+15|1630000000.00000000|2021-08-26 17:46:40|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: what is "T" here?

Comment: @martian_rover imports were missing, sorry !

Comment: datatype in schema is still string not timestamp for "date" column

Comment: @martian_rover just cast it : `F.from_unixtime("date_num").cast("timestamp")`

Comment: it is returning same timestamp for all rows

Comment: Yes. Same input = same ouput. There is no magic. If the whole column has the same value `1.63E+15`, you will have the same timestamp ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238063/discussion-between-steven-and-martian-rover).